# Sharepoint 2010 : File path too long error during wsp file creation in MSBuild

Tags: 2010

We noticed our TFS build started failing with the following message:

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\MyProject Release\Sources\MyProject\MainLine\MyProject.SharePoint.EnterpriseUI.SiteDefinition\Features\MasterPagesMyProject\MasterPagesMyProject.feature: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

This seems rather strange in this day and age. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because of the way our company names our projects, I had this same problem.  We name them something like CompanyName.SharePoint.SolutionName.  When you view the properties of your feature, there is a property called deployment path which usually looks like this:

$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$

I ended up removing the first token, $SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$, and replacing it with a short name that represents our company.  Doing this and trying to keep my feature names short fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Steve,Thank you for the suggestion. However, I cannot find the deployment path property you mention. In VS2010/Sp2010, I double click on MyFeature.feature in VS, and all I get is the Items in solution/Items in Feature dialog. Where should I be looking for it?

Comment: It's not on the main page but on the properties window.  Hit F4 for this window to show.  Also make sure you double click on the feature for the properties to show in this window.